# Android build doesn't start

Tags: monaca

I was trying to build an Android APK on Monaca IDE and after selecting the type (Debug/Release) a new window appears exactly with the same content (selection of build type).
After selecting (again) the build, nothing happens, only a blank screen and the build doesn’t start. The problem appears in release and debug builds.

This appear in full screen **after** selecting the build type on the IDE:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/0vV0J.png

Then, after selecting the build type **again**, only a blank screen:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/XVUZA.png

My best guess is that's a bug in the IDE and has got nothing to do with the project but for what it's worth I’m using Onsen UI V2, plain JS w/o a framework.

Answer (score 0):

After a few tries and some frustation, I finally solved the problem:

1. exit Monaca
2. clear cookies (using a new Chrome user should also work)
3. login to Monaca